# PHP imagejpeg - convert output to base64

Tags: php, base64, imagejpeg

I am generating a simple text in an image like this...

```
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
```

I need the output as a base64 string, I have tried base64_encode($im) but it is not working correctly for me.

Does anybody have an example I can see?

Comment: $im is a resource, you can't use it as a string. Get the imagejpeg result and base64encode it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `ob_get_clean` function to get the image from the output buffer and then encode it to base64:

```
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

ob_start();

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

$img = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);

echo base64_encode($img);
```